# System freeze when network-manager active on ASUS X99-PRO

Tags: networking, asus, freeze

After experiencing random system freezes I think I've narrowed it down to the Wi-Fi networking. Every time I have my machine up and running > more than 24 hours it seems to crash and the last log entries indicate that it relates to the network. This has also happened when I manually change the Wi-Fi network. The freeze stops everything - the mouse doesn't move, external drives stop loading data, and I can't `ctrl+alt+f2`, `ctrl+alt+backspace` or [REISUB](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_shortcuts) on the system. The motherboard is an [ASUS X99-PRO](https://www.asus.com/se/Motherboards/X99PRO/HelpDesk_Download/) with the latest BIOS 3301 installed.

The `kern.log` tail:

```
Sep  5 21:42:37 nnx NetworkManager[30306]: <info>  [1473104557.3002] dhcp4 (wlp5s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Sep  5 21:42:37 nnx NetworkManager[30306]: <info>  [1473104557.3020] device (wlp5s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
Sep  5 21:42:37 nnx NetworkManager[30306]: <info>  [1473104557.3025] device (wlp5s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
Sep  5 21:42:37 nnx NetworkManager[30306]: <info>  [1473104557.3031] device (wlp5s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Sep  5 21:42:37 nnx NetworkManager[30306]: <info>  [1473104557.3033] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Sep  5 21:42:37 nnx NetworkManager[30306]: <info>  [1473104557.3224] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Sep  5 21:42:37 nnx NetworkManager[30306]: <info>  [1473104557.3225] policy: set 'my_network' (wlp5s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Sep  5 21:42:37 nnx NetworkManager[30306]: <info>  [1473104557.3392] DNS: starting dnsmasq...
Sep  5 21:42:37 nnx NetworkManager[30306]: <warn>  [1473104557.3403] dnsmasq[0x1f7a840]: dnsmasq not found on the bus. The nameserver update will be sent when dnsmasq appears
Sep  5 21:42:37 nnx NetworkManager[30306]: <info>  [1473104557.3403] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Sep  5 21:42:37 nnx NetworkManager[30306]: <info>  [1473104557.3876] device (wlp5s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Sep  5 21:42:37 nnx NetworkManager[30306]: <info>  [1473104557.3880] manager: startup complete
Sep  5 21:42:37 nnx NetworkManager[30306]: <info>  [1473104557.3924] dnsmasq[0x1f7a840]: dnsmasq appeared as :1.162
Sep  5 21:42:37 nnx NetworkManager[30306]: <info>  [1473104557.3925] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Sep  5 21:42:42 nnx NetworkManager[30306]: <info>  [1473104562.2120] WiFi hardware radio set enabled
Sep  5 21:42:42 nnx NetworkManager[30306]: <info>  [1473104562.2120] WWAN hardware radio set enabled
```

Here's the same section (timewise) from `syslog`:

```
Sep  5 21:42:37 nnx whoopsie[4298]: [21:42:37] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Sep  5 21:42:37 nnx whoopsie[4298]: [21:42:37] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Sep  5 21:42:37 nnx systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Sep  5 21:42:37 nnx systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Sep  5 21:42:37 nnx systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Sep  5 21:42:37 nnx systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Sep  5 21:42:38 nnx gnome-session[5363]: (deja-dup-monitor:6110): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 233 was not found when attempting to remove it
Sep  5 21:42:38 nnx whoopsie[4298]: [21:42:38] online
Sep  5 21:42:38 nnx avahi-daemon[4267]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp5s0.IPv6 with address xxx::xxx:aaa:aaa:bbb.
Sep  5 21:42:38 nnx avahi-daemon[4267]: New relevant interface wlp5s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Sep  5 21:42:38 nnx avahi-daemon[4267]: Registering new address record for fe80::62da:f2c5:93bc:298f on wlp5s0.*.
Sep  5 21:42:42 nnx NetworkManager[30306]: <info>  [1473104562.2120] WiFi hardware radio set enabled
Sep  5 21:42:42 nnx NetworkManager[30306]: <info>  [1473104562.2120] WWAN hardware radio set enabled
```

The `dmesg` is currently empty. I've also done a memcheck that passed without any errors. I've also reinstalled 16.04 and made sure everything is up-to-date.

I tried recently to just turn off the service via `sudo service network-manager stop` and then the system ran fine. About 30 minutes after I had turned it on again it crashed with the report above.

**Question**: Apart from getting a USB-WiFi dongle - any ideas why this is happening? Is there something that I'm missing or is this a bug with the onboard Wi-Fi that ships with the X99-PRO?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the freezes for months. Trying different things. Other kernels. something with nvidea. Installing WICD, etc etc.

And then a view day´s ago a little comment in a post saying :

Remove modemmanager

```
sudo apt remove modemmanager
```

that did the trick for me.

I am using a MacBookPro 2012.

hope it will help others too.

source : [NetworkManager Daemon Hangs Computer.][1]

[1]: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/networkmanager-daemon-hangs-computer-893058/#post4422775     *bottom of the page*

Answer (score 0):

I am having a near identical issue with a Asus X99-E WS motherboard with BIOS version 3502. The crashes are exactly as described with the same kern.log tail. I am disabling Networkmanager via:

```
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
```

and so far it's working (4 days)

Comment: I am having far fewer crashes in recent times. Maybe due to Nvidia, kernel, or firmware changes on my Mint 18.3 machine.